# React Native - Tipsi-stripe Error - 'Cannot read property 'init' of undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe into my React-Native project by following the Tipsi-stripe installation and linking guide:
https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/installation.html

1. I started by `npm i --save tipsi-stripe`,
2. Added `Podfile` and run cmd: `pod install`,
3. Drag and dropped 'TPSStripe' folder from node_modules into my Xcode project file (this was a very vague step in the guide).
4. Automatically linked the packages by running this cmd: `react-native link tipsi-stripe`

But now I get this error screen in my simulator:

```
Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0JZ5.png)

I came across similar problems on other forums and I suspect it's a linking issue. I followed the exact instructions on the guide but cannot understand why I am still getting this error.

Here is a screenshot of my .xcodeproj file inside Xcode. The TPSStripe folder I inserted is also inserted as shown in the image. Is this in the right place??:

[xcodeproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI7G1.png)

There appears to be a lot of files in the explorer highlighted Red which I don't understand why.

And here is a close-up of some errors showing in Xcode:

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsy0d.png)

Does anyone have similar problems?

Comment: yes i have the same issue! you found a cure?

Comment: according to your attached image! your bundle iD for iOS is not on the Store account of yours and you don't seem to have enabled merchant ID

Comment: I did get it working, although can't pinpoint exactly what the issue was. I tried several times and it appeared to be a linking issue. I posted what worked for me on this GitHub post under xeb10154: https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/349

Answer (score 0):

if you add the library to the pods you don't have to link them

Comment: Do you mean moving the TPSStripe folder into the Pods folder? Or are you talking about the .xcodeproj files?